# PHP Register form is not inserting credentials into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I have a database with a single table called `Users` and 6 columns
(`userID (primary), prenume, nume, nicknamee, parola, tara`)
I want to develop a user registration system. For now, I only want the user to type in the username / nickname and the password. The problem is that when I press submit, the credentials are not inserted into the database. Can someone please help me out?

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<?php
$servername = hhhhh;
$username = hiuhiuhiuh;
$password = theseAreSecret;
$dbname = shhhh;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully\n";




?>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Campfire</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Username:
        <input type="text" name="nicknamee" value="Username"><br>
        Password:
        <input type="password" name="password" value="Password"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="submit">
        <?php
    if ( isset( $_POST['Submit1'] ) ) { 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (userID, prenume, nume, nicknamee, parola, tara)
        VALUES (5, 'John', 'Snow', '$_POST[nicknamee]', '$_POST[password]', 'Romania')";}
        ?>
    </form>

</body>

<?php

// Print everything out
$result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES");
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() ){
    $table = $row[0];
 echo '<h3>',$table,'</h3>';
$result1 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
if($result1) {
    echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
    $column = $conn->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
echo '<tr>';
    while($row3 = $column->fetch_row() ) {
    echo '<th>'.$row3[0].'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';
    while($row2 = $result1->fetch_row() ) {
      echo '<tr>';
      foreach($row2 as $key=>$value) {
        echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
      }
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table><br />';
  }
  }
echo '<br>';echo '<br>';echo '<br>';echo '<br>';

$conn->close();

?>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, this registration form is vulnerable to sql injection. You can read more about it here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: First line of your PHP code and there's already a syntax error. As Arin said, put on errors, it will help you a lot. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the row isn't being added to the database is because the query isn't executing. It is simply setting `$sql` to your query. Now all you need to do is execute the query using `$conn->query($sql)`.

By the way, the values of the variables `$servername`, `$username`, `$password`, and `$dbname` should be in double (") or single (') quotes.

And a few other issues...

- When it echos "Connected Successfully\n", it echos a `\n`. HTML uses `<br>` though.
- There's an empty `<link rel="stylesheet" href="">` in the `<head>`.
- There are a few security issues with this. Refer to the bottom of this answer for more info.

Here's the corrected code:

```
<html>
<?php
$servername = 'hhhhh';
$username   = 'hiuhiuhiuh';
$password   = 'theseAreSecret';
$dbname     = 'shhhh';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully<br>";    
?>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Campfire</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Username:
        <input type="text" name="nicknamee" value="Username"><br>
        Password:
        <input type="password" name="password" value="Password"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="submit">
        <?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (userID, prenume, nume, nicknamee, parola, tara)
        VALUES (5, 'John', 'Snow', '$_POST[nicknamee]', '$_POST[password]', 'Romania')";
    $conn->query($sql); // this line was missing
}
?>
    </form>

</body>

<?php

// Print everything out
$result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES");
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $table = $row[0];
    echo '<h3>', $table, '</h3>';
    $result1 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
    if ($result1) {
        echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
        $column = $conn->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
        echo '<tr>';
        while ($row3 = $column->fetch_row()) {
            echo '<th>' . $row3[0] . '</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        while ($row2 = $result1->fetch_row()) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($row2 as $key => $value) {
                echo '<td>', $value, '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table><br />';
    }
}
echo '<br><br><br><br>';

$conn->close();

?>
</html>
```

There are a few security issues with this setup though.

- You may want to hash the passwords for better security. You can read more about that [here](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- It is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)
- You probably don't want to echo the tables that contain your password.
- The form doesn't have a [CSRF token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) that is submitted with it. That isn't a huge problem, but someone could use it to spam your site. For example, they would create several `<iframe>`s on their site that would submit a post request to generate spam users.
- It is vulnerable to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) because it prints the rows. Someone could insert something like `<script>alert(1)</script>` into the database, and it would print it to the page and trigger an alert. I'd suggest encoding the responses with `htmlspecialchars($html)`.

Answer (score 0):

if no connection issue you should execute query that insert your data into database.

You just have your query string `$sql` but never execute.

after this line;
    `$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (userID, prenume, nume, nicknamee, parola, tara) VALUES (5, 'John', 'Snow', '$_POST[nicknamee]', '$_POST[password]', 'Romania')";`

try;

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Generally it is not a good idea to print the SQL error. It is OK in development, but keep in mind that if you plan on making the site public, you should remove the error printing.